# Can an string variable contain an int

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a string variable `string SQLstr = "SELECT [column] FROM [DB].[Table] WHERE [column]= {0}"`. This works perfectly fine when querying `VARCHAR` columns, but if I have query an int columns, then I get an error, presumably because it is querying an int column with a string.

Since `textBox1.Text` is user input, is there any way that I can make it be interpreted as an int when running `SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format(SQLstrL,textBox1.Text), conn)`?

Comment: That doesn't make sense... please provide a complete example of the scenario which doesn't work, and include the error message.

Comment: Yes there is. It is called using parameters. The pattern you have here is absolutely NOT how you should ever write another query. This is wide open to sql injection. If you use parameters you prevent injection and have complete control over datatypes. Fix this before [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) comes to visit.

Comment: Your code is subjecto to SQL injection, you should seriously consider adopting parameters in your queries

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

**DON'T DO THIS**

What you have is *dangerously vulnerable* to SQL Injection attacks; it's practically begging to get hacked.

There is a better way to accomplish the same kind of thing which is safe from these attacks and also solves your string vs int issue:

```
string SQLstr = "SELECT [column] FROM [DB].[Table] WHERE [column]= @Parameter";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn);
cmd.Parameter.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

or

```
string SQLstr = "SELECT [column] FROM [DB].[Table] WHERE [column]= @Parameter";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn);
cmd.Parameter.Add("@Parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

Note you still must know what kind of value you expect for that spot in the query. **Nothing** saves you from this, because we live in a strongly-typed world. Even the `AddWithValue()` method, which can infer your data type, has [significant reasons not to use it](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try concatenating an empty string in the end of the sql result. If the result is a (boxed) int then the + "" will force it to be converted to a string.

I agree with the comments about SQL injection risk. This is not something that you could release to the public unless the textbox were very constrained.